# How to use variables in xslt xpath expressions

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have something like the following code::

```
<xsl:variable name="sample">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//foo">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//bar">
</xsl>
```

And in a template I’d like to use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$sample/*">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, `$sample/*` does not seem to be a valid xpath expression or return a node-set and I can't quite figure out, how to fix it.
I also tried just plain `$sample`, but that isn't a node-set either :/
Any ideas, what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using XSLT 1? You can't apply xpath expressions to variables in XSLT 1. 
You can in XSLT 2 however.

Depending on your XSLT processor you may have access to a custom extension such as EXSLT's node-set function.

Comment: Thanks, that’s it. The exsl:node-set function works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

There's actually two other solutions available next to switching to an XSLT 2.0 processor.
One is applying a processor dependent function as Kevan says, for instance `msxsl:node-set()` or `xalan:nodeset()` or `exsl:node-set()`.
The other is to make use of the fact that `xsl:variable` `select` attribute includes a conversion of a `result tree fragment` such as your sample variable to a node-set; hence defining a new variable with select attribute equal to the one to be addressed, will do the trick:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp" select= "$sample"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$temp/*">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:for-each>
```